# Add disk space to the / partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted, root, ram

I have a dual boot system with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 17.04, and I have 20Gb of free unallocated space that I want to add to my Ubuntu `/` partition because I'm running out of space.

[image: Here is a screen from GParted]

I'm a beginner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Important note:**
>
> Although normally everything works fine, there is a small risk of something going wrong when modifying your partitions, resulting in data loss.
>
> Therefore you should **always have a current back-up of your important files** before starting.

- Boot from a live system, e.g. from the Ubuntu installer DVD/USB drive. Select "Try Ubuntu without installing" in the boot menu.
- Start GParted on the live system.
- Select your Ubuntu root partition `/dev/sda8`, right-click on it and click on <kbd>Resize/Move</kbd>.
- Enlarge the partition by either dragging the left border of its graphic visualization to the left so that it covers up all unallocated space, or manually enter a value in the `Free space preceeding` field (probably you want 0 or whatever minimal value it allows to keep the partitions properly aligned).
- Confirm your modification with the <kbd>Resize/Move</kbd> button.
- Let GParted begin its work by clicking the green check button labelled "Apply all operations".
- Once it is finished, reboot into your normal Ubuntu system on the disk. Done.

Comment: Ok so you can resize (this way ) either **left** or **right** provided the free space lies adjacent to the target partition?

Comment: Yes, in the screenshot in the question, the unallocated space is directly on the left of the root partition. Therefore nothing else needs to be moved around. You still need to boot from a live system because you can (should) not resize a mounted partition and you can not unmount the root partition you booted from.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the size of / on the run. You would have to boot from a live USB and then resize / with Gparted. This can be a risky process as your boot loader GRUB may point to an area of space for starting Ubuntu that has been moved.

Comment: Couldn't you boot into `/bin/bash` with `init=/bin/bash` then use `parted` or `fdisk`  to resize?